# Track the status of a CloudFront signed url download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In the project where I'm working, we are distributing large files (various GB) using Amazon CloudFront. As the files are private, when a user requests one download, we generate a signed url valid for a certain period of time.

Then, the question is that we would like to know, given one of the urls, the progress of the download. I think that using the CloudFront logs we will be able to know at which time the link has been used, and if it is the case, we can assume that the download has started, but do you know if there is some way to know the progress of the download?

Thanks!